# Going back to previous page after page redirection

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Hi I am tring to send a user to the login page if he is not authetificated and after he logs in I want to send him back to the page he was the problem is I am getting only half way to the page I want the user to be.Here is my code:

When I user clicks a button in my application I check if the user is logged in if he is not.I refirect him to the loggin page with this protion of code:

```
 return RedirectToAction("LogIn" , "Account" , new { returnUrl = "Products" , subCat = Request.QueryString["subcat"]});
```

What I would expect to get out of this code is:

LogIn?returnUrl="Products"&subCat="Notebooks"

What I get is this:

```
Products?subcat=Notebooks
```

This is the link from the page I cliked the button from.Now this behavior may be because the links are all created using ajax.ActionLink but if that is true how can I get back to my previous page?

I have not modified the default routing of the MVC application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `returnUrl` like this `returnUrl = ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.PathAndQuery` and leave the `subcat` alone.